# Django fixture creation, ignoring relations between objects

Tags: django, testing, python-3.6

I'm testing views in a django app. There are a lot of OneToMany and ManyToMany relations between models (users, departments, reports, etc.) It takes a lot of time upfilling certain fields like name, surname date of birth etc. while creating fixture which I dont use at all. How can I ignore them? Also what are the best practices while creating a fixture? Mine lools like this

```
class TestReportModel(TestCase):
allow_database_queries = True

@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    cls.report_id = 99
    cls.factory = RequestFactory()

    cls.user_with_access = User.objects.create(username="user1", password="password")
    cls.employee = Employee.objects.create(user=cls.user_with_access, fio="name1 surname1",
                                           date_of_birth="2012-12-12")
    cls.indicator = Indicator.objects.create(context_id=10, set_id=10)
    cls.ife = IndicatorsForEmployees.objects.create(employee=cls.employee, indicator=cls.indicator)
    cls.report = Report.objects.create(owner=cls.ife)
    cls.report.id = cls.report_id
    cls.report.save()

    cls.user_with_no_access = User.objects.create(username="user_with_no_access", password="password")
    cls.employee_with_no_access = Employee.objects.create(user=cls.user_with_no_access, fio="name2 surname2",
                                                          date_of_birth="2018-12-12")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to specify a test database in your settings file, load a fixture with syncdb, then use the keepdb flag.

In your settings file, you can specify a test database name within databases. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE-TEST

If this database is not found, it will be created when you run the tests. Once your fixture is created, you can use syncdb to load that db. 
https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Fixtures#Fixtures

Then when you run your unit tests, pass `--keepdb` with it and the database will persist between tests. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-keepdb

Comment: Is there any way to write in settings somehow so that I don't write it every time?

Comment: @АйдарМулюков The keepdb is passed as an argument on the command line, not in settings.